# Is the dimethylglyoximate anion ambidentate or not?

Tags: coordination-compounds

In class, my professor said that dimethylglyoximate is a special ambidemtate ligand that can donate lone pairs via both nitrogen (which it normally does), and oxygen (very rarely).

On googling whether it is ambidentate or not, I didn't find anything. Can anyone cite an example where dmgH is donating lone pairs of electrons via oxygen and not nitrogen?

If this doesn't exist, can someone confirm that dmgH is not ambidentate?

Comment: Here is an example, in which the oxygen atoms serve as "bridging" functions http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1990/dt/dt9900000469#!divAbstract

Comment: Still, I don't know any case of dmgH complexes in which the ligand bounds with O and N to a single metal center (and I wonder if it could even be possible, since I think that a good orbital alignment with both O and N on the same metal center couldn't be possible)

Comment: @The_Vinz thanks for that, can you further explain why there won't be a good orbital alignment? I don't know how it works..

Comment: The reason why I said that is because (writing the Lewis structure might help) in the O-N-C-C-N-O chain, nitrogen is planar and sp2, and carbon is planar and sp2. Now, if you wanted oxygen to approach the metal center, you should force a rotation around the double CN bond, or hope in a O-M electron interation, but being O so distant, that's highly unlikely to happen, unless I'm missing something.
Also, note that if you rotated the CC single bond to somehow accomodate oxygen, the nitrogen's lone pair would lose its alignment with the metal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this example qualifies as an example for dimethylglyoximate acting as an ambidentate ligand, because it, for me, is more like bidentate. Nonetheless, I'm presenting this example here only because both nitrogen and oxygen are donating lone pairs within the same molecule. See trinuclear copper complex below ([ref: doi.org/10.1107/S160053680301331X](https://doi.org/10.1107/S160053680301331X)):

[image: trinuclear copper complex]

Comment: I was taught that we would call a ligand "ambidentate" when it donates electrons from _either_ one atom _or_ the other atom, but not both at once. For example, either S or N in $\ce{SCN-}$, but not both at once. But, in the example above, both are acting as donors at once. How does that count as ambidentate?

Comment: @Gaurang Tandon: That's my point as well.  But I wasn't sure  when it donate lone pairs via nitrogen and oxygen to two different $\ce{Cu}$ atoms.

Comment: @GaurangTandon there are many cases (look under Complexes in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethylglyoxime) where dimethylglyoximate acts as a donor through 2 nitrogens, and now an example where it donates via one oxygen and one nitrogen. Hence it's ambidentate.

Comment: @GaurangTandon SCN- can also be bridging ligand. That's a consequence of ambidentacity.